# React Toggle open and close using onclick on map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

I have an `onClick` in map function, if I click `onClick` it will change state of all map item not that item which I clicked. I am using `useState` hook.

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

{
  FilterAvailable.map((item, id) => {
    return (
      <li className="filterItem">
        <div
          className="filterBtn flex align-center justify-between"
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        >
          <h2>{item.catogery}</h2>
          <div>
            {open ? (
              <IoIosArrowDown className="downArrow" />
            ) : (
              <IoIosArrowUp className="downArrow" />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        {item.options.map(option => {
          return (
            <>
              {open && (
                <ul className="filterOption">
                  <li className="filterOptionitem">
                    <button>{option}</button>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              )}
              {/* <div className="hrLine"></div> */}
            </>
          );
        })}
      </li>
    );
  });
}
```

> I want to open only those item option which click.

Comment: You have your `onClick` function on a button outside the map function. If you want to open an individual item, you must include that `onClick` inside the button inside the `map` as well as the index for that item, so if the index of that item matches, it will only open that only. You can have the index as a second argument in the .map function

Answer (score 1):

Your state is in the wrong place, you need to break the component and have a open state per filterableItem

```js
const Filters = () => {
  return FilterAvailable.map((item, id) => {
    return <FilterItem item={item} />;
  });
};

const FilterItem = ({ item }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <li className="filterItem">
      <div
        className="filterBtn flex align-center justify-between"
        onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
      >
        <h2>{item.catogery}</h2>
        <div>
          {open ? (
            <IoIosArrowDown className="downArrow" />
          ) : (
            <IoIosArrowUp className="downArrow" />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      {item.options.map(option => {
        return (
          <>
            {open && (
              <ul className="filterOption">
                <li className="filterOptionitem">
                  <button>{option}</button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            )}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </li>
  );
};
```

Comment: One more problem. I want to get value of option with item category  when click on it how can i achive this, kindly guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Put the index inside state on onclick , inside map check if state index equals to map index and you are done

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving the mapped elements to their own component with props - then you create and set your open and closed state there.